# How to enable start-deployment for AWS Amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

I want to use [start-deployment](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/start-deployment.html) for AWS Amplify but my CLI tells me it cannot find that command. How come? It is [just one of the features](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/index.html#cli-aws-amplify). And how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, I assume that you are trying to call a binary named *amplify*. What you should do instead is to call the amplify **command** (see synopsis [1]) of the aws cli binary.

Your invocation should therefore look something like:
`aws amplify start-deployment --app-id xxxxx --branch-name xxxxx`

[1] https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html#synopsis